# The Yandex index robot is redirected when requesting this site so the robots.txt file will not be used. What's the fix?

Tags: redirects, https, sitemap, robots.txt, yandex

We have a website:
`www.example.com` which redirects to `https://www.example.com`.

Therefore when you type `www.example.com/robots.txt` you are redirected to `https://www.example.com/robots.txt`.

Another point to note:
The main mirror in Yandex will be decided by the crawler, it won't allow us to set `www.example.com` or set `https://www.example.com` as the main mirror.

Please note: This error that I am getting

`The Yandex index robot is redirected when requesting this site so the robots.txt file will not be used` is from this page : 
https://webmaster.yandex.com/robots.xml

---

**Update:**

We updated our Robots.txt to the following after the answers.

```
    User-agent: Yandex
    Sitemap: https://www.example.com/sitemap.xml
    Disallow: /some_pages/
    Host: https://www.example.com

    User-agent: *
    Sitemap: https://www.example.com/sitemap.xml
    Disallow: /some_pages/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a main mirror in Yandex.
I think you need something like this:

```
Host: myhost.ru # uses

User-agent: *
Disallow: /cgi-bin

User-agent: Yandex
Disallow: /cgi-bin
Host: www.myhost.ru # is not used
```

or even:

```
# domen.myhost.com is the main mirror
# www.domen.myhost.com, is the correct use of 
# the host Host directive:User-Agent: *
Disallow:Host: domen.myhost.com
```

The Host directive should contain:

> ```
> An HTTPS protocol indication if the mirror is only available via a protected channel (Host: https://myhost.com).
>
> One concrete domain name that corresponds to RFC 952 and is not an IP-address.
>
> The port number, if necessary (Host: myhost.com:8080).
> ```

More information : https://yandex.com/support/webmaster/controlling-robot/robots-txt.xml

Comment: Hi @knif3r I made and edit to the question. The error is something I am receiving when I am trying validate and submit the robots.txt file. So I can't even seem to submit the robots file to Yandex at this point.

Will your fix sort that out?

Comment: According to Yandex support yes : You should specify https domain as the main mirror in your robots.txt file and then wait for a couple of weeks. When the main mirror changes according to your settings, your website will be able to start indexing and appear in search results at https protocol. You can find more information about the fact what websites are considered to be mirrors by Yandex on page

Comment: I made an error, updated your answer by mistake.
Also, we updated our robots.txt file to the above, does this seem correct?

Comment: @Ratan No worries, I caught the update and made it clearer in your question.

Comment: Yes I think it is correct I don't know if you need to add `https://` to the host altought, you can just leave `wwww.`